# onNotificationOpenedApp & getInitialNotification don't fire anymore on IOS (expo)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
async function onMessageReceived({ title, body, orderId }: { title: string; body: string; orderId?: string }) {
    await notifee.createChannel({
      id: "main",
      name: "Main",
      sound: "default",
      vibration: false,
      importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
    });

    await notifee.displayNotification({
      title,
      body,
      android: {
        channelId: "main",
        badgeCount: 0,
      },
      ios: {
        badgeCount: 0,
        sound: "default",
      },
    });

    notifee.onBackgroundEvent(({ type, detail }) => {
      if (type === EventType.PRESS && orderId && isAuthenticated) {
        navigate("order", { id: Number(orderId) });
      }
    });
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async (remoteMessage) => {
      Alert.alert("Notification caused app to open from background state:", JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });

    messaging().getInitialNotification().then(async (remoteMessage) => {
      Alert.alert("Notification caused app to open from background state:", JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });

    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      // console.log({ remoteMessage });
      // Alert.alert("A new FCM message arrived!", JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));

      await onMessageReceived({
        title: remoteMessage.notification?.title ?? "",
        body: remoteMessage.notification?.body ?? "",
        orderId: remoteMessage.data?.orderId,
      });
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

This is my logic for handling the events

This is my code for the `setBackgroundMessageHandler`:

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
  console.log("Message handled in the background!", remoteMessage);
  // you could do things like incrementing badge count, doesnt work tho
  await notifee.incrementBadgeCount();
});
```

It appears the `setBackgroundMessageHandler` doesn't fire.

On android the `onNotificationOpenedApp` & `getInitialNotification` works perfect but on ios it stopped working. It worked before, but now i can't get it working anymore.

Comment: We ended up not going with notifee anymore, but i've had contact with them and something i used was deprecated. You can check the right implementation here: https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/events

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me! I'm thinking of switching to Notifee too